# How do I create a direction blue dot like Google Map using OSMDROID?

Tags: java, openstreetmap, osmdroid

[image]

I am using open street Map tool of osmdroid

How can I create a blue dot with direction pointing base on direction bearing?

I only find out how to add marker in OSMDROID, what is the blue dot call in osmdroid?

Answer (score 0):

I did this a few years ago, I don't know if Osmdroid has changed in the mean time. I was overriding `overlay` and its `draw` method, inserting my bitmap.

As I said, this is old code, check with the current API before you use it.

```
public class MyLocationOverlay extends Overlay implements MyLocationListener {

private static final String TAG = MyLocationOverlay.class.getSimpleName();

private BoundedMapView mapView;
private Point point = new Point();
private Bitmap myLocationMarker;
private Bitmap haloMarker;
private Location myLocation;
private Bitmap bm;
private MyLocationManager locationManager;

public MyLocationOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker, ResourceProxy pResourceProxy,
        Context context, MapView mapView, MyLocationManager locationManager,
        BitmapUtils bitmapUtils) {
    super(pResourceProxy);
    this.mapView = (BoundedMapView) mapView;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inMutable = true;

    myLocationMarker = bitmapUtils.rotateIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.getResources(), R.drawable.trackingdot, options));
    haloMarker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.trackingdothalo);
    myLocation = locationManager.getMyLocation();
    this.locationManager = locationManager;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

    /*
     * draw my location
     */
    if (myLocation != null) {
        try {
            point = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(
                    new GeoPoint(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()), point);
            canvas.drawBitmap(myLocationMarker, point.x - (myLocationMarker.getWidth() / 2),
                    point.y - (myLocationMarker.getWidth() / 2), null);

            int size = (int) mapView.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(
                    myLocation.getAccuracy());

            if (bm != null) {
                bm.recycle();
            }
            if (size > 40) {
                bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(haloMarker, size, size, false);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bm, point.x - (bm.getWidth() / 2), point.y
                        - (bm.getHeight() / 2), null);
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage() == null ? "OutOfMemoryError" : e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage() == null ? "IllegalArgumentException" : e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    myLocation = location;
    mapView.postInvalidate();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    if (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equalsIgnoreCase(provider)) {
        myLocation = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    if (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equalsIgnoreCase(provider)) {
        myLocation = locationManager.getMyLocation();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    if (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equalsIgnoreCase(provider)
            && status == LocationProvider.AVAILABLE) {
        myLocation = locationManager.getMyLocation();
    }
}

@Override
public void onExitEnterPark(InParkStatus inParkStatus) {

}
```

}

Comment: Can I see your whole code?
new GeoPoint(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()), point);

Where do u declare point in this line?

Comment: I added the whole class. As I said, it's old code, check with the current api. Don't pay attention to the `rotateIcon` bit, my map had East at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: install osmonuspack
(https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0)

Step 2: download osmand and get icons from osmand;

- blue arrow (map_navigation_default)
- or similar to the icon above (map_location_default)

Step 3: Change DirectedLocationOverlay icon:

```
    myLocationOverlay = new DirectedLocationOverlay(this);
```

- first choice, Single bitmap;

  ```
    // 1-Single Bitmap
    Drawable d = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.direction_arrow, null);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
  ```
- or second option, Blue Arrow;

  ```
    // 2-Single LayerDrawable - Blue Arrow
    LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_navigation_default);
    final int width = ld.getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int height = ld.getIntrinsicHeight();
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    ld.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    ld.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
  ```
- or third option, similar to the icon above;

  ```
     //3- Double layerdrawable
    Drawable bottom = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.map_location_default_view_angle);
    Drawable top = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.map_location_default);
    final LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{bottom, top});
    final int width = ld.getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int height = ld.getIntrinsicHeight();
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    ld.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    ld.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
  ```
- change icon;

  ```
    myLocationOverlay.setDirectionArrow(bitmap);
    map.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
  ```